CURL do not free memory inside a thread without a active host
I need to call several POST requests every second with an image and I can't wait for any response When my host is active  everything works good. But when the host is offline, the memory increase fast and CURL does not clean the memory .
Function:

void send_tcp_event_metadata_and_image(std::string xml_text, std::string m_server_ip, std::string logPathforerror, cv::Mat sentimage, std::string plate) {

        POSTRequestMutex.lock();

        int sent = 1;
        cv::Mat image = sentimage.clone();
        sentimage.release();

        CURL* curl;
        CURLcode res;

        // initialize curl librarie
        curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);
        curl = curl_easy_init();

        try
        {

            int imageheight = image.rows;
            int imagewidht = image.cols;
            int imagesize = image.total() * image.elemSize();


            vector<int> paramsAlarm;

            paramsAlarm.push_back(cv::IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY);
            paramsAlarm.push_back(90);

            vector<uchar>outbuf;
            std::string extention = ".jpg";

            std::string imagebase64 = "";
            try {

                cv::imencode(extention.c_str(), image, outbuf, paramsAlarm);

                auto base64_jpg = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(outbuf.data());

                imagebase64 = base64_encode_invenzi(base64_jpg, outbuf.size());

                outbuf.clear();

            }
            catch (...) {

                //image.release();

            }

            paramsAlarm.clear();


            // define where the image goes
            std::string metadata_flag1 = "$image";

            // find the metadata flag in xml string
            if (xml_text.find(metadata_flag1) != std::string::npos) {

                xml_text.replace(xml_text.find(metadata_flag1), 6, imagebase64);
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "==================> ERROR <==================" << endl;
                std::cout << "$metadata$ Flag could not be found" << endl;
                std::cout << "==================> ERROR <==================" << endl;
                //return 0;
            }


            // define where the metadata goes
            std::string metadata_flag5 = "$plate";

            // find the metadata flag in xml string
            if (xml_text.find(metadata_flag5) != std::string::npos) {
                xml_text.replace(xml_text.find(metadata_flag5), 6, plate);
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "==================> ERROR <==================" << endl;
                std::cout << "$metadata$ Flag could not be found" << endl;
                std::cout << "==================> ERROR <==================" << endl;
                //return 0;
            }

            bool Trigged = false;

            if (curl) {


                std::string readBuffer;

                printf("trying to get post event \n");

                //time_t theTime = time(NULL);
                //struct tm* aTime = localtime(&theTime);

                string url2 = m_server_ip;
                boost::replace_all(url2, " ", "%20");
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url2.c_str());
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, xml_text.c_str());
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1L);
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 1);
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2L);
                struct curl_slist* slist = NULL;

                slist = curl_slist_append(slist, "Accept: */*");
                slist = curl_slist_append(slist, "Content-Type: text/xml");


                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, slist);
                //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);


                /* example.com is redirected, so we tell libcurl to follow redirection */
                //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);

                /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
                res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

                /* Check for errors */
                if (res != CURLE_OK) {

                    sent = 1;

                }
                else {

                    sent = 0;
                }

                curl_slist_free_all(slist);
            }


        }
        catch (...) {


        }


        /* always cleanup */
        if (curl)
         curl_easy_cleanup(curl);


        curl_global_cleanup();

        image.release();


        POSTRequestMutex.unlock();




}

How I am calling the function:

// threads
boost::asio::thread_pool Algopool(16);

for(;;) {  //just an example of the infinite loop 
                                                                                                 
  string invenzidata(ConfigData.configAreas[p].TCPdata);
                                                                                        
  string invenziaddress = ConfigData.configAreas[p].TCPaddress;
                                                                                        
  string LogPath = logPathforerror;

                                                                                        
  boost::asio::post(Algopool, [=]() {                                                                   
    InvenziDriver IvenziEvent;                                                                                                     
    IvenziEvent.send_tcp_event_metadata_and_image(invenzidata, invenziaddress, LogPath, imCrop, plate);
  });
}

Using without thread it works but I need speed on this, I can't wait for the response.
UPDATE ----------------------------------------------------------
I create a minimalexample here that anyone can test it will increase the memory very quickly:
// testcurlthread.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//
#include <iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/replace.hpp>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

//#include <opencv2/dnn.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/video/background_segm.hpp>


using namespace std;

class PostwithImage {


    std::string base64_chars =
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
        "0123456789+/";

private:


    std::mutex POSTRequestMutex;

    boost::system::error_code error;
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::asio::streambuf receive_buffer;

    std::string base64_encode_invenzi(unsigned char const* bytes_to_encode, unsigned int in_len) {
        std::string ret;
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        unsigned char char_array_3[3];
        unsigned char char_array_4[4];

        while (in_len--) {
            char_array_3[i++] = *(bytes_to_encode++);
            if (i == 3) {
                char_array_4[0] = (char_array_3[0] & 0xfc) >> 2;
                char_array_4[1] = ((char_array_3[0] & 0x03) << 4) + ((char_array_3[1] & 0xf0) >> 4);
                char_array_4[2] = ((char_array_3[1] & 0x0f) << 2) + ((char_array_3[2] & 0xc0) >> 6);
                char_array_4[3] = char_array_3[2] & 0x3f;

                for (i = 0; (i < 4); i++)
                    ret += base64_chars[char_array_4[i]];
                i = 0;
            }
        }

        if (i)
        {
            for (j = i; j < 3; j++)
                char_array_3[j] = '\0';

            char_array_4[0] = (char_array_3[0] & 0xfc) >> 2;
            char_array_4[1] = ((char_array_3[0] & 0x03) << 4) + ((char_array_3[1] & 0xf0) >> 4);
            char_array_4[2] = ((char_array_3[1] & 0x0f) << 2) + ((char_array_3[2] & 0xc0) >> 6);

            for (j = 0; (j < i + 1); j++)
                ret += base64_chars[char_array_4[j]];

            while ((i++ < 3))
                ret += '=';

        }

        return ret;

    }

public:

    PostwithImage() { };


    std::string parseIP(std::string parseData) {

        std::string data = parseData;

        std::string delimiter = ":";

        size_t pos = 0;
        std::string token = "";

        std::stringstream ss(data);
        std::string to;

        while (std::getline(ss, to, '\n')) {
            cout << to << endl;
            std::string s = to;
            while ((pos = s.find(delimiter)) != std::string::npos) {
                token = s.substr(0, pos);

                std::cout << token << std::endl;

                break;
            }
        }


        cout << "IP: " << token << "\n";
        return  token;

    }


    int parsePort(std::string parseData) {


        std::string data = parseData;

        std::string delimiter = ":";

        size_t pos = 0;
        std::string token = "";

        std::stringstream ss(data);
        std::string to;

        while (std::getline(ss, to, '\n')) {
            cout << to << endl;
            std::string s = to;
            while ((pos = s.find(delimiter)) != std::string::npos) {
                token = s.substr(pos + 1, data.length());

                std::cout << token << std::endl;
                break;
            }
        }


        cout << "port: " << token << "\n";
        return  atoi(token.c_str());


    }


    void send_tcp_event_metadata_and_image(std::string xml_text, std::string m_server_ip, std::string logPathforerror, cv::Mat sentimage, std::string plate) {

        int sent = 1;
        cv::Mat image = sentimage.clone();
        sentimage.release();

        CURL* curl;
        CURLcode res;

        // initialize curl librarie
        curl = curl_easy_init();

        try
        {

            int imageheight = image.rows;
            int imagewidht = image.cols;
            int imagesize = image.total() * image.elemSize();


            vector<int> paramsAlarm;

            paramsAlarm.push_back(cv::IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY);
            paramsAlarm.push_back(90);

            vector<uchar>outbuf;
            std::string extention = ".jpg";

            std::string imagebase64 = "";
            try {

                cv::imencode(extention.c_str(), image, outbuf, paramsAlarm);

                auto base64_jpg = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(outbuf.data());

                imagebase64 = base64_encode_invenzi(base64_jpg, outbuf.size());

                outbuf.clear();

            }
            catch (...) {

                //image.release();

            }

            paramsAlarm.clear();


            // define where the image goes
            std::string metadata_flag1 = "$image";

            // find the metadata flag in xml string
            if (xml_text.find(metadata_flag1) != std::string::npos) {

                xml_text.replace(xml_text.find(metadata_flag1), 6, imagebase64);
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "==================> ERROR <==================" << endl;
                std::cout << "$metadata$ Flag could not be found" << endl;
                std::cout << "==================> ERROR <==================" << endl;
                //return 0;
            }


            // define where the metadata goes
            std::string metadata_flag5 = "$plate";

            // find the metadata flag in xml string
            if (xml_text.find(metadata_flag5) != std::string::npos) {
                xml_text.replace(xml_text.find(metadata_flag5), 6, plate);
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "==================> ERROR <==================" << endl;
                std::cout << "$metadata$ Flag could not be found" << endl;
                std::cout << "==================> ERROR <==================" << endl;
                //return 0;
            }

            bool Trigged = false;

            if (curl) {


                std::string readBuffer;

                printf("trying to get post event \n");

                //time_t theTime = time(NULL);
                //struct tm* aTime = localtime(&theTime);

                string url2 = m_server_ip;
                boost::replace_all(url2, " ", "%20");
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url2.c_str());
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, xml_text.c_str());
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1L);
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 1);
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2L);
                struct curl_slist* slist = NULL;

                slist = curl_slist_append(slist, "Accept: */*");
                slist = curl_slist_append(slist, "Content-Type: text/xml");


                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, slist);
                //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);


                /* example.com is redirected, so we tell libcurl to follow redirection */
                //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);

                /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
                res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

                /* Check for errors */
                if (res != CURLE_OK) {

                    sent = 1;

                }
                else {

                    sent = 0;
                }

                curl_slist_free_all(slist);
            }


        }
        catch (...) {

        }

        /* always cleanup */
        if (curl)
            curl_easy_cleanup(curl);


        image.release();

    }


};


int main()
{
    // threads
    boost::asio::thread_pool Algopool(16);

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);

    for (;;) {


        string invenzidata = "{\"placa\":\"$plate\", \"cameraname\":\"camera01\",\"image\":\"$image\"}";
        string invenziaddress = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/notification";
        string LogPath = "C:/Logs";

        string plate = "asd0000";
        cv::Mat imCrop = cv::imread("C:\\test.jpg");


        boost::asio::post(Algopool, [=]() {
            PostwithImage postClass;
            postClass.send_tcp_event_metadata_and_image(invenzidata, invenziaddress, LogPath, imCrop, plate);
            });


        imCrop.release();
    }

    curl_global_cleanup();

}


Please try to create a minimal reproducible example.

As you have a mutex you can only handle one request at a time so having a thread pool is a little pointless. Seems odd to do curl_global_init for every request? Why not just do it once

This system has zero support for pushback or throttling, as you experienced. The question is: are you allowed to drop images if they are not making it through?

Curl is not to blame here, it's your lambda taking that cv::Image by copy.

Thanks for the reply, I was not calling every curl_global_init, it was a try to see if with curl_global_cleanup() could help. But it do not clean the memory. I need to copy the image with the lambda because I can't wait the thread to finish. But I try
sentimage.release(); inside de function to release image memory. The most strange on this is that if the host is online all memory go back to normal at once.

The mutex was another attempt to avoid the problem. But has no sense. Because for every call I am creating a new instance of 'InvenziDriver IvenziEvent;' It shouldn't have data race as I am copying the data with lambda =

You don't even get to sentimage.release(), because of the mutex. While the first request sits there for two seconds until timing out, you keep adding more, and they all are stuck on POSTRequestMutex.lock(); while holding a copy of the image in memory.

Using Mutex or not I have the same result because every call is a new instance of this class.

I updated the question with a  minimal reproducible example as suggested by @AndréLehto

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Mutex or no mutex, you pile up send_tcp_event_metadata_and_image calls as fast as you can, then each call sits blocking for two seconds while holding at least three copies of the image data in memory (one in image, another in imagebase64, the third in xml_text). This has nothing to do with Curl - it doesn't own any of that memory and is not responsible for cleaning it.
